# Missing H264 and mpeg profile/encoders in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, mpeg

I'm trying to record video from a connected USB camera using ffmpeg on ubuntu.

When I input

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 15 -s 800x600  -i /dev/video0 output.avi
```

i get the following error:

> [mpeg4_v4l2m2m @ 0x4d79d0] mpeg4 profile not found

Similarly when i use

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 15 -s 800x600  -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

i get

> [h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x4c1ec0] h264 profile not found

I installed ffmpeg using apt install. Does ayone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Got resolved when I uninstalled it and built from source using this guide

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu